# apt does not want to clear updated packages

Tags: apt

Does anyone know how to clear packages that apt shows as upgradeable but already on last version?

```
$ apt list --upgradable

Listing... Done

code/bionic 1.28.1-1539281690 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.28.1-1539281690]

thunderbird/bionic 1:60.2.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:60.2.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1]
```

I tried clearing cache, upgrading, removing and installing again and the only option for now is to mark ignored and manually update.

Thanks

Edit: added policy update

```
thunderbird:
  Installed: 1:60.2.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
  Candidate: 1:60.2.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
  Version table:
     1:60.2.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 500
        500 http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary bionic/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1:60.2.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:52.9.1+build3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
     1:52.7.0+build1-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy code thunderbird` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert, you are correct. I have pop os as repo with higher priority. What is my best option to correct this without removing pop os repo?

Comment: Usually [apt-pin](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto) is used for such purposes. But it may lead to unpredictable results. You can check the current settings by viewing files in `/etc/apt/preferences` and `/etc/apt/preferences.d/`. Just curious, why you have Pop_OS! repositories in the system? Was it preinstalled or added by yourself?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you have this packages from different maintainers. Try to do `apt list -a -- thunderbird` and you will see all available versions of this package. Then you maybe will have to get rid of some repositories which contain this package.

Or you could just try upgrade your OS: `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` or `sudo apt full-upgrade`.